# Execute Powershell commands remotely

Tags: powershell, psexec

I have a linux server with `winexe` package installed. It's the same as PSExec, and everything works okay when running simple commands, but when I run it with this command below I get a parsing error!

```
winexe -U user%password //host "powershell -Command (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://host/filename.iso","c:\file.iso")"
```

Can anyone figure what's wrong with this?  Is it's cause a conflict in the quotes around the url and file name, with the quotes around the whole command?

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the format: `powershell.exe -Command "& {<command>}"`

This worked for me, using your example:

```
powershell.exe -Command "& {(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://google.com/robots.txt','c:\robots.txt')}"
```

Also, I used single-quotes in `DownloadFile`

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Nested use of double quotes won't work.
Try something like this:

```
winexe -U user%password //host "powershell -Command (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://host/filename.iso','c:\file.iso')"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to run the command directly using single quote. For example listing the processes can be done as follows:

```
winexe -U "Domain\PC-Name" //IP Address 'powershell.exe Get-Process'
```